# Suggestions for lazy loading images plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

I'm in search of most popular and working `lazy loading images` plugin for **jQuery** which would normally sustain large amounts of images per page.

I have tried following plugins:
 - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
 - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/
 - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imageloader/

Non of them suites my needs. First didn't work as it should, second overloads server with requests, third couldn't get running. I know, that last one isn't **jQuery**, but I was desperate.

Would be really appreciated if anyone could suggest anything.

**UPD:**
Okei, my mistake. First plugin works as it is described, but it still works to slow with needed amount of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the plugin Andrew mentions ([JAIL](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail) a.k.a. JqueryAsynchImageLoader) and it works well, and is very easy to use. By default you have to use the `data-href` attribute to store your actual image. Afterwards you simply call `$("#yourdiv").asynchImageLoader()` to enable asynchronous image loading. That's all.

Comment: Well this isn't actually a correct answer, but I will accept it since I found a better solution already and there is no point in keeping this question open any longer.

Comment: What's wrong with it? It handles quite a large number of images for me (hundreds). And what are you using now instead?

Comment: Just plain simple parsing. I tried using JAIL and it loaded images just a bit slower than now, but what for should I use plugin when I can do it with simple two lines of code. When image in range, then place value from some attribute into src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin might suit.
It appears to be in active development, but I have not tried it out yet.
it does require you to make changes to the HTML IMG tags.

http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail